# Solr 4.10.3 indexing nested documents with array of objects

Tags: arrays, object, solr, nested, block

I'm trying to store a json that looks like:

```
{
        "id": "44444",
        "headline": "testing US",
        "generaltags": [
            {
                "type": "person",
                "name": "Jayalalitha",
                "relevance": "0.334",
                "count": 1
            },
            {
                "type": "person",
                "name": "Kumar",
                "relevance": "0.234",
                "count": 1
            }
        ],
        "socialtags": {
            "type": "SocialTag",
            "name": "US",
            "importance": 2
        },
        "topic": {
            "type": "Topic",
            "name": "US",
            "score": "0.936"
        }
    }
```

notice how **generaltags** is an **array of objects**.

I'm using Solr 4.10.3 and I'm using a schemaless mode (ManagedIndexSchemaFactory)

when I try to import such a json from the my local admin single document import interface:

/solr/#/schemaless1/documents

I get the following error:

```
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 400,
    "QTime": 1
  },
  "error": {
    "msg": "Error parsing JSON field value. Unexpected OBJECT_START",
    "code": 400
  }
}
```

how should I proceed? Is there a way to store that specific object without changing its structure ( I'm getting the object from some APIs and would prefer to leave it as it is without needing to parse it) .

Thank you

Comment: I guess nested objects should have own ID, but your objects in generaltags - don't have it.

Comment: could you check your example on Solr 5.3+ ? And please look on http://yonik.com/solr-nested-objects/

Comment: Assigning id didn't solve it. I still get the same error. Also unfortunately I have a hard constraint on the Solr version. I have to use 4.10.3. Any other ideas? @iMysak